# Socket.io alternative

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, websocket

I apologise in advance that this might get flagged and closed for being an opinion-based thread but this is purely a fact-finding mission. I'm very new to the world of web sockets and the only reputable library I'm aware of is [socket.io](http://socket.io/) and the site is currently down so I'm taking the opportunity to discover another library. I'm building a MEAN app and I'd like the ability to have communication between clients and a central server, all in real-time which is where socket.io would come into play but are there any other alternatives I should know about?

(My server is written with Express 4)

Comment: If you are looking for lightweight lib, I wrote a library that has much of what socket.io offers with a much lighter footprint: https://github.com/bminer/ws-wrapper

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few days ago Socket.io 1.0 was released (previous version was 0.9). The official website http://socket.io seems to being updated too (as well as Socket.io's Github wiki page). I visited a new version of the website just yesterday and it was `200 OK`.

As for your question - well, this is really opinion-based, and in my opinion Socket.io provides all you need to build cross-browser real-time applications, so I would recommend using it. Socket.io is good because:

- It has a variety of transports between client and server: WebSockets, XHR long polling, JSONP, Flashsockets, etc. (**Important note:** since version 1.0 Socket.io is able to change transport on a fly without messages loss)
- It has rooms support
- It has auto-reconnect support
- It has simple and convenient API
- It has simple integration with Express and Koa
- It has large community
- It is fully cross-browser

Though if you want to know more about alternatives, take a look at [SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node). This is a framework similar to Socket.io. But since I have never used it I can't tell how good it is.

Good luck and sorry for my English :)

Comment: SockJS is not maintained anymore.

Comment: SockJS seems maintained fine, actually

Comment: Even though closed, top result for "socket.io alternative".... Personally i dislike the fact it requires node.js or fallsback to flash.. (i could be mistaken at this point) ... A pure client side with other options for different server side would be best.. switching to node.js is something i hope never happens... its not needed personally..

Comment: Yeah ... just good luck installing that on windows ...

Comment: Not sure what you mean, on Windows doing node.js dev and have no issue running socket.io... what seems to be your isue?

Comment: the only problem is that it has a memory leak :( otherwise its great! Eventually if you have too many users it will hang and restart the node app (with pm2). socket.io fails to remove cache or something...